# How to auto fill form data?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have two questions:

1) I am trying to fill a form's fields with data from a mysql table. But for some unknown reason, I am getting a trailing `/` at the end of the values as soon as I put them in a text field.

```
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" <?php echo('value='.checkDefaultValue($vals['user_firstname'])); ?>/>
```

The function

```
function checkDefaultValue($val,$ret="")
    {
        if($val=="" || $val=='not specified')
        {
            return $ret;
        }
        else
        {
            return $val;
        }
    }
```

however if I just echo `<?php echo('value='.checkDefaultValue($vals['user_firstname'])); ?>`

I don't get the trailing `/` at the end of the value. Any ideas guys?

2) What is the best way to fill the data in the form from db? I am basically making an `edit profile` kind of thing, and I want the values to be pre filled in their respective fields. Oh, and this has no need of ajax and such...

Comment: Are you sure the slash you were seeing wasn't just the one at the end of the input tag to indicate a self-closing tag: `<input value=default/>`? (If so, make sure you put quotes around the value)

Comment: Alternative tip: Don't use XHTML syntax. If you send it with the wrong mime type (text/html) like everyone else, it's just interpreted as HTML with trailing garbage. Also unless you embed another namespaces it's fully purposeless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget the quotes:

```
<input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" value="<?php echo checkDefaultValue($vals['user_firstname']); ?>" />
```

Comment: And also don't forget the `htmlentities()`

Comment: oops...silly me. Thanks. But what's the answer to my second question?

Answer (score 1):

For your #2 question, there's only one way to fill in a field: set the field's `value` attribute. Whether you do this at page generation time server-side, or on the client-side using AJAX or plain-jane Javascript is irrelevant - you're still just populating the form fields with the value attribute (or selectedIndex or textarea contents, whatever).

If you're doing it server-side, you MUST pass the values through `htmlspecialchars()`, otherwise the data you're inserting can potentially break the form if they contain any of the HTML metacharacters (`'`, `"`, `<`, `>`) and lead to an XSS vulnerability on your site.

If you're doing it client-side, then you'll have to do the equivalent escaping with `json_encode()` and the like, to prevent any stray `'` in the data from breaking the Javascript.